# Сложные объекты в Struts 2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, struts

Из JavaScript в Java action (использую Struts 2) нужно предать сложный объект:

объект 1 уровня, в нём несколько объектов 2 уровня, а в объектах 2 уровня есть несколько объектов 3 уровня.

Чтобы всё нормально работало, использую такой подход:

**JS:**

```
    for(var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        var currentModule = $(modules[i]);
        newCable['cable.modules['+ i +'].order'] = currentModule.find(".moduleOrder").html();
        newCable['cable.modules['+ i +'].type'] = currentModule.find(".fiberTypeSelect option:selected").val();
        newCable['cable.modules['+ i +'].color'] = currentModule.find(".moduleColorNameSelect option:selected").val();
        var fibers = currentModule.find(".fiberRowDiv");
        for(var j = 0; j < fibers.length; j++) {
            var currentFiber = $(fibers[j]);
            newCable['cable.modules['+ i +'].fibers['+ j +'].order'] = currentFiber.find(".fiberOrder").html();
            newCable['cable.modules['+ i +'].fibers['+ j +'].color'] = currentFiber.find(".fiberColorNameSelect option:selected").val();
        }
    }
    $.getJSON('/BSS/resources/cablesAddCable.action?struts.enableJSONValidation=true',
    newCable
    , function(response) {}...
```

Благодаря этому параметры в запросе имеют вид

> cable.modules[0].order 1
>
> cable.modules[0].fiber[0].type    0

и т.д.

При таком формировании в Java объект автоматически определяется нормально и с ним можно работать (все объекты описаны в отдельных классах).

```
private Cable cable;
public void setCable(Cable cable) {
    this.cable = cable;
}
public Cable getCable() {
    return cable;
}
```

Т. е. все внутренние переменные объекта, включая вложенные `List`'ы объектов заполняются нормально.

Подскажите, а нет ли более *элегантного* способа?

Answer (score 1):

Я тут думал насчет элегантного способа, и конечно же он есть. Хотя сам способ при котором используется OGNL для популяции объектов хорош, только незачем передавать параметры GET запросом, к тому же без их кодирования. Для передачи надо использовать POST метод.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/BSS/resources/cablesAddCable.action?struts.enableJSONValidation=true",     
   data : newCable,
   dataType:"JSON",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
.done(function(response) {});
```

Далее json интерсептор должен принять данные и разбросать их по объектам, если `newCable` это нормальный JSON.